Reading text file in Pyspark with delimiters present within double quotes
I have text file similar to the below example
I am using the encoder ISO-8859-1 as and separator as þ
The raw data is something like this of name "test.txt"
idþnameþroleþ expþ task_descþ comp
1þJohn Doeþ"Senior Developerþ 4þ working on the PySpark project"þ Google
I need the data to look like this



id
name
role
exp
task_desc
comp




1
John Doe
"Senior Developer
4
working on the PySpark project"
Google



I am using the below code to run the raw "test.txt" file
spark_df = spark.read.options( multiline='True', quote='"', escape='"', encoding='ISO-8859-1', mode='PERMISSIVE').csv('test.txt', header=True, sep='þ')

I have also used the below mentioned quote and escape characters.
quote="\"", escape="\""
Is there a solution to this problem in Pyspark?

You are using the quote='"' option to suppress field checks inside quoted strings. Remove that option and it should do what you want.

You need to have quote='' to make it work.
